# AbstractPersistable for Optaplanner Persistence

Tags: persistence, optaplanner

I've noticed that all of the examples in Optaplanner use the line

```
import org.optaplanner.examples.common.domain.AbstractPersistable;
```

to import an abstract class that most of the domain classes implement. To persist my solution to an xml file, should I also utilize this class? My maven project would need to have org.optaplanner.examples as a dependency, which I am hesitant to do.

I've read the source for AbstractPersistable, and I can't tell what benefits it provides to the example projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't depend on `optaplanner-examples`.**

- You probably don't need that class, just leave it out.
- If you want to have that superclass that provides a database id, for every domain class, simply copy paste that class into your sources.